# How to upload a json file to firebase database from Android phone?

Tags: android, firebase

How to upload json file to firebase?
**I wish upload a json file to firebase from my android phone. Help me**

Comment: Did you made any attempt? Did you faced any errors? Did you even tried?

Comment: I think first read and parse a json file. Then create class. Add each Object to class firebase